# Интеграция Youtube shorts на сайт

Tags: html, jquery

Загвоздка в следующем. На страницу сайта надо интегрировать видео Shorts из Youtube. Так как их большое кол-во на странице, то это очень сильно нагружает её и все долго грузится. Мы решили сделать "подмену". То есть изначально в разметке ссылка с картинкой внутри обложкой этого шортса. При клике на ссылку, в jq меняем ссылку на новую, которая уже подгружает само видео. Проблема в том, что именно к шортсам этот способ почему-то не работает, а с обычными видео - все ок.
Ниже пример.

```js
$(() => {
  $('.js-play-video').click(function replaceVideo(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const $this = $(this);
    const $videoLink = $this.prop('href');
    const $video = $(`<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="${$videoLink}" 
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`);
    $this.replaceWith($video);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="advantages-page__shorts-item">
          <a class="advantages-page__shorts-item__link js-play-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/shorts/Th8Xt2-GHts">
            <img src="//img.youtube.com/vi/Th8Xt2-GHts/maxresdefault.jpg">
          </a>
        </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ютуб не позволяет встраивать shorts, встраивайте как обычное видео `https://www.youtube.com/embed/Th8Xt2-GHts`